# RestClient has been removed from this version of the library (TWILIO)

Tags: node.js, twilio-api

> throw new Error(this.constructor.name + ' has been removed from this
>   version of the library. Please refer to
>   https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node for more information.')
>           ^ Error: RestClient has been removed from this version of the library. Please refer to https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node
>   for more information.
>       at RestClient.ObsoleteClient (C:\carsapp\node_modules\twilio\lib\base\obsolete.js:7:9)
>       at new RestClient (C:\carsapp\node_modules\twilio\lib\base\obsolete.js:12:21)
>       at Object. (C:\carsapp\helpers\twilio_restful_client_connection.ts:6:34)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
>       at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\Andrey Radkevich\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:422:23)
>       at Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
>       at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (C:\Users\Andrey
>   Radkevich\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:425:12)
>       at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. (C:\carsapp\helpers\sing-in-up-helper.ts:8:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
>       at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\Andrey Radkevich\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:422:23)
>       at Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)

```
const accountSid = 'AC2a54bb2c4ea4992593cc9f0ca2f720c0';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const Client = require('twilio').RestClient;

const client = new Client(accountSid, authToken);

client.outgoingCallerIds.create(
  {
    friendlyName: 'My Home Phone Number',
    phoneNumber: '+14158675310',
  },
  (err, callerId) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(callerId.sid);
    }
  }
);
```

I have got this error when I tried to create this part of the code above. I tried to add a number to Twilio whitelist ( verify phone number).How can I make it in another way? I use for this Node js

Link on this part of the code in the documentation : 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/outgoing-caller-ids

Answer (score 0):

```
const accountSid = 'AC2a54bb2c4ea4992593cc9f0ca2f720c0';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.validationRequests
  .create({
    friendlyName: 'My Home Phone Number',
    phoneNumber: '+14158675310',
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data.validationCode));
```

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/outgoing-caller-ids#add-an-outgoing-caller-id

Here answer on my own question